How to Handle Large Numbers from Oracle Database in Dart
In an Oracle database, I have a column car_id of type NUMBER, and one of the values is 145225607533994638226526393421876737461.
What data type should I use in Dart/Flutter to define this in a class? Should I use BigInt?
For example:
class Car {
  BigInt? carId;
  ...
}

In view I'm use  to_char(car_id) as car_id but this "neutralize indexes"

Maybe String could be a better choice in this case but also BigInt should work...

Since that seems like a big integer value, BigInt makes sense. Did you try it? Any specific question for us that i not a recommendation?

https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#yes-no-question

I suspect that it should be a string column in the database. It isn't really a number, it's just a string that happens to use the characters 0-9. For example, to get the paint code, you might need to extract the 18th-20th characters, to get the engine type it might be the 22nd-25th characters, and so on. There will never be calculations involving the car_id.

From the Dart docs int type is limited to  64 bits signed intergers. So, in your case, you should use Bigint to store your number in the Oracle DB. However, to maintain data integrity, when you retrieve the car_id from the database, you can convert it to a BigInt using BigInt.parse as shown below:
BigInt carId = BigInt.parse(carIdString);

